# Mongo is only storing date in ISO_8601 format instead of unix

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unix, iso8601

i am trying to store in collection in UNIX format but its is stored everytime in ISO_8601 format.
Below is my code, can you please have a quick glance and tell where am i going wrong?

```
var date = Date.now();

var comments = new Comments({
    item_id : req.params.item_id,
    content : req.body.content,
    created_at: date,
    updated_at : "",
    is_deleted : 0
});
```

**Comment Schema**

```
var CommentsSchema = new Schema({
    content: {type: String},
    item_id: {type: Number},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    is_deleted: Number
});
```

But when i `console.log()` the content in comments object, its showing date in ISO_8601 format. I even tried to use `moment js` for the same but in vain.

Comment: What is your `created_at` type in mongodb?

Comment: wait, i will edit and out the schema as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store timestamps in your database, you should use `type : Number` in the schema, and not `type : Date`.

Otherwise Mongoose will automatically convert the timestamps to a proper `Date` instance when reading the data from the database (from which you can still extract the timestamp though, using `doc.created_at.getTime()`).

Answer (score 0):

> Mongoose v4.x has time stamping as a built-in option to a schema

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema( {key:keyType,}, {timestamps: true} );
```

---

```
var CommentsSchema = new Schema({
    content: {type: String},
    item_id: {type: Number},
    is_deleted: Number
},{timestamps: true});
```

> This option adds `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties that are `timestamped` with a `Date`, and which does all the work for you. Update  request updates the document, it updates the updatedAt property

**Example**

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);
var thing = new Thing();
thing.save(); // `created_at` & `updatedAt` will be included
```

> By default, the name of two fields are createdAt and updatedAt, custom the field name by setting timestamps.createdAt and timestamps.updatedAt.

See the [document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) for more details